# Filter correlation matrix R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, correlation

I am a little bit stuck trying to extract the data from a correlation matrix, I'm looking to extract values that are higher than 0.8 and lower than 0.99 since I want to exclude the correlation of two stocks that are exactly 1.

this is my code:

```
  #Test 

#load the packages
library(corrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(dplyr)
library(quantmod)

#get the data needed
startdate <- "2001-01-03"

tickers <- c("MMM", "AA", "AXP", "T", "BAC")
portfolioprices <- NULL

for(ticker in tickers)
  portfolioprices <- cbind(portfolioprices, getSymbols(ticker, from=startdate, auto.assign=F)[,4])
colnames(portfolioprices) <- tickers

#check if there is nothing wrong with the data
print(portfolioprices)

#create a correlation matrix and plot it
correlations <- cor(as.matrix(portfolioprices))
correlations <- as.data.frame(correlations)
correlations
ggcorrplot(correlations, hc.order = TRUE, type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE)
```

as output I get:

```
           MMM          AA        AXP           T        BAC
MMM  1.0000000 -0.40325223  0.8772498  0.39019025 -0.2406640
AA  -0.4032522  1.00000000 -0.3029517  0.06347736  0.8383226
AXP  0.8772498 -0.30295171  1.0000000  0.41189453 -0.1304659
T    0.3901902  0.06347736  0.4118945  1.00000000 -0.1297723
BAC -0.2406640  0.83832262 -0.1304659 -0.12977234  1.0000000
```

This is the data frame where I would ideally extract the data that are positively correlated with a minimum value of 0.8.

I don't know if I am going about this completely the wrong way or not and any feedback is welcome!

EDIT:

Ideally I would prefer the data to come out like this:

```
          MMM          AA        AXP           T        BAC
MMM                          0.8772498  
AA                                                  0.8383226
AXP  0.8772498 
T    
BAC               0.83832262
```

Where only the relevant positive values would get filtered.
Removing the non identical values.

MMM:AXP = 0.8772498
BAC:AA = 0.8382262

If this is possible at all.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I suggest you think about and share with us what you expect that frame to look like when the specified numbers have been removed. Some thoughts: (1) are you certain all you need is strong positive correlation, or is -0.99 to -0.8 good, too? (2) Is replacing the non-matching numbers with `NA` what you're thinking of? If not, the expected-output is even more important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add this line at the end of your code

```
correlations[correlations < 0.8 | correlations ==1] <- ""
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Load in your data that makes it easy for others to reproduce your results:

```
dat <- structure(list(MMM = c(1, -0.4032522, 0.8772498, 0.3901902, -0.240664
), AA = c(-0.40325223, 1, -0.30295171, 0.06347736, 0.83832262
), AXP = c(0.8772498, -0.3029517, 1, 0.4118945, -0.1304659), 
T = c(0.39019025, 0.06347736, 0.41189453, 1, -0.12977234), 
BAC = c(-0.240664, 0.8383226, -0.1304659, -0.1297723, 1)), 
.Names = c("MMM", "AA", "AXP", "T", "BAC"), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("MMM", "AA", "AXP", "T", "BAC"))
```

Now just get the index and use subsetting on the names of the matrix.

```
index <- which(abs(dat) > .80 & abs(dat) < 1, # your criteria
               arr.ind = T) # the result of the which function is now in rows & columns
cbind.data.frame(stock1 = rownames(dat)[index[,1]], # get the row name 
                 stock2 = colnames(dat)[index[,2]]) # get the column name
#      stock1 stock2
#1    AXP    MMM
#2    BAC     AA
#3    MMM    AXP
#4     AA    BAC
```

**I've assumed you wanted high absolute correlation (for predictability) -- but if you only want stocks that move in tandem *in the same direction*, simply remove the `abs` functions.